# Rounding numbers to the nearest values (with different intervals) in R

Tags: r, rounding

I want to round (or replace) numbers in `a`

```
a <- c(0.505, 1.555, 2.667, 53.850, 411.793)
```

to the nearest values in `b`:

```
b <- c(0, 5, 10, 50, 100, 200, 500)
```

The output will be this:

```
a_rnd <- c(0, 0, 5, 50, 500)
```

The logic is simple but I couldn't find any solution, because all the approaches I found require values in `b` have an equal interval!

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to loop over all values of `a` and use these indexes to extract the proper `b` values

```
b[sapply(a, function(x) which.min(abs(x - b)))]
#> [1]   0   0   5  50 500
```

Comment: I wanted to see which method was faster, your `sapply` or my `apply`.  `microbenchmark::microbenchmark` says your median time is better, but my mean time is better, because yours occasionally has a very large time.  Strange!  I prefer yours for clarity though.

Comment: I actually did the same and noticed that it seems to be always the first iteration which is slower than all subsequent iterations. This smells like some caching is going on here but I am not sure^^
However, sapply should scale better since it does not create a large matrix as an intermediate step.

Comment: @mnist, it might be JIT compiling your anonymous function.

Comment: would you mind elaborating on this a bit more or sharing some sources?

Answer (score 2):

This is a relatively simple approach:

```
b[apply(abs(outer(a, b, "-")), 1, which.min)]
```